# php opnssl_decrypt producing null

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, cryptojs

i am trying to encrypt email and password using crypto js and then decrypt in CodeIgniter framework.
In my Jquery i have done this the encryption text produced is

"UGGAnirzSbsaL33+Bjtz1jhsD+bzqRmkJcWZx9nylfo="

```
var a = $('#email').val();

    var key = "6fa979f20126cb08aa645a8f495f6d85";
    var iv =  "I8zyA4lVhMCaJ5Kg";

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(a, key, {iv:iv});
    encrypted = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    $('#email').val(encrypted)
```

I am sending var encrypted in my php file.

in my php code i have

```
function cryptoJsAesDecrypt($enc_text){

    $encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC";
    $key = "6fa979f20126cb08aa645a8f495f6d85";
    $iv =  "I8zyA4lVhMCaJ5Kg";
    $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($enc_text);

    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_dec, $encryptionMethod, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv);

    print_r('fsdfds---'.$enc_text);die;

    return $decrypted;
}
```

where $enc_text="UGGAnirzSbsaL33+Bjtz1jhsD+bzqRmkJcWZx9nylfo=";
now when trying to print the decrypted text nothing is being printed.
when i am printing $ciphertext_dec is shows the following:-
$ciphertext_dec =Pa��*�I�/}�;s�8l���%ř����

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it by changing my code in jquery

```
    var a = $('#email').val();

    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('efac4330be072b5193dadf5d1a945a1344bab61a7d48114324c3aacaa440ab3c');
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('E8446FCBAE01B5B7A0F18B826D1C46D2');

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(a, key, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
    var ciphertext = encrypted.toString();
```

and changing my PHP code to

```
function cryptoJsAesDecrypt($enc_text){


        $encryptedText = base64_decode($enc_text);
        $key = hex2bin("efac4330be072b5193dadf5d1a945a1344bab61a7d48114324c3aacaa440ab3c");
        $iv = hex2bin("E8446FCBAE01B5B7A0F18B826D1C46D2");

        $decryptedText = openssl_decrypt($encryptedText, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

        return $decryptedText;
    }
```

this resolved my issue and i was able to successfully decrypt my encrypted text.